# Sum all instances of a particular node in a SQL Server XML column

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following xml data column:

```
<AccountingDetail>
    <DetailItems>
        <AccountingDetailItem>
            <Credit>25</Credit>
            <Debit>15100</Debit>
        </AccountingDetailItem>
        <AccountingDetailItem>
            <Credit>5</Credit>
            <Debit>150.66</Debit>
        </AccountingDetailItem>
    </DetailItems>
</AccountingDetail>
```

How do I get a sum of all credits and all debits in this column? The number of instances varies from row to row.

I expect sum(debits) = 15250.66 & sum(credits) = 30

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with a CTE (Common Table Expression) - something like this (assuming our XML data is stored in a `@XmlData XML` variable):

```
-- define the CTE to extract the individual Credit and Debit values
;WITH RawXmlData (Credit, Debit) AS
(
    SELECT
        Credit = ISNULL(XC.value('(Credit)[1]', 'decimal(16,4)'), 0.0),
        Debit = ISNULL(XC.value('(Debit)[1]', 'decimal(16,4)'), 0.0)
    FROM
        @XmlData.nodes('/AccountingDetail/DetailItems/AccountingDetailItem') XT(XC)
)
-- now select from that CTE and sum up the values
SELECT
    SumCredit = SUM(Credit),
    SumDebit = SUM(Debit)
FROM
    RawXmlData
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved within XML/XQuery which should perform better, than creating a derived set and do the aggregation externally:

```sql
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(N'<AccountingDetail>
    <DetailItems>
        <AccountingDetailItem>
            <Credit>25</Credit>
            <Debit>15100</Debit>
        </AccountingDetailItem>
        <AccountingDetailItem>
            <Credit>5</Credit>
            <Debit>150.66</Debit>
        </AccountingDetailItem>
    </DetailItems>
</AccountingDetail>')
,('<AccountingDetail>
    <DetailItems>
        <AccountingDetailItem>
            <Credit>10</Credit>
            <Debit>20</Debit>
        </AccountingDetailItem>
        <AccountingDetailItem>
            <Credit>20</Credit>
            <Debit>40</Debit>
        </AccountingDetailItem>
        <AccountingDetailItem>
            <Credit>30</Credit>
            <Debit>60</Debit>
        </AccountingDetailItem>
    </DetailItems>
</AccountingDetail>');

SELECT t.YourXml.value('sum(//Credit)','decimal(16,4)') AS SumCredit
      ,t.YourXml.value('sum(//Debit)','decimal(16,4)') AS SumDebit
FROM @tbl t;
```